# show latest titles of posts in specific category in drupal 6

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules, drupal-taxonomy

I want to get latest titles of posts in specific category in Drupal 6

e.g. to get 10 latest posts in a category

in wordpress I use this code:

```
query_posts("cat=200&showposts=10")
```

I'd appreciate your help

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use 'views' module.  You can create any list of posts in it and choose category, number of posts for showing on the page.
Read here http://mimiflynn.com/blog/2011/04/07/drupal-views-baby-steps/